# The meaning of 'changing fortunes'

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have a piece of exercise requesting me to make sentences about a businessman's **changing fortunes**. There are some of these sentences:

> Alexander won a small fortune in a casino when his luck was good.
>   Alexander lost a fortune in a business that went bankrupt.

I think that the two **fortune** in these two sentences mean **an amount of money**, but I don't think **fortunes** means amounts of money in the phrase **changing fortunes**. I've seen a lot of news' titles contain **changing fortunes** and there are even a book named this phrase. What does it mean in the request of my homework?

Comment: Sorry I can't get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct to think that *lost a fortune* and *a small fortune* are referring to wealth.

Changing fortune refers to the following definition:

> The success or failure of a person or enterprise over a period of time.

Therefore, by changing their fortunes, the person or business is changing the successfulness of their business. I don't think I've ever seen it used to mean decrease the successfulness, it usually implies a positive result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "he lost a fortune" and "he earned a fortune (e.g. from his various businesses)" speaks about large amounts of money.

But it also has a meaning of ["The turns of luck in the course of one's life"](http://thefreedictionary.com/fortune) (American Heritage dictionary)

E. g. it's possible to say:

> [His fortune turned.](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=pgq8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=%22his+fortune+turned%22&source=bl&ots=Gt-GYmKP6J&sig=odgHF8vohtMuI78V7T8NpSKWPRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDsYOusf3YAhUH1SwKHaPiAMI4ChDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22his%20fortune%20turned%22&f=false)